# Difference transferring funds with wallet adapter with web3js transfer instruction on front end versus calling contract method and transfer there?

Tags: transfer, solana-wallet-adapter

What is faster? I am having a simple app that transfers money from one wallet to another wallet. Based that functionality only does simple transfer, is there a point making a smart contract and having something like following in contract method:

```
**src.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? = src
        .lamports()
        .checked_sub(amount)
        .ok_or(ProgramError::InvalidArgument)?;
    **dst.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? = dst
        .lamports()
        .checked_add(amount)
        .ok_or(ProgramError::InvalidArgument)?;
```

Is there even point using smart contract for simple transferring, or should i just use wallet adapter and track stuff in database? What would be the benefit of using smart contract for this? What about performance difference?

Comment: "should i just use wallet adapter and track stuff in database?" The answer is going to come down to what you need to store, whether that data would be better on or off chain and whether it should/shouldn't be stored atomically with the transfer. What data do you want to store?

Comment: i am not storing anything on chain. i have a contract that does an operation onchain, some transfers, depositing some funds to PDA, thus doing via smart contract, but now i will not use PDA anymore since i want to do middle operation offchain due to solana issues, and will just have deposit and withdrawal to common wallet address directly to save complexity and do middle operation offchain, thus just thinking to abolish smart contract and do stuff without contract.